# Summarizing rows of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I tried the following to convert my `Data` into my `Desired_output` without success.

I wonder what I'm missing?

```
library(tidyverse)

group_by(Data, ID) %>% 
  summarise(Den=Den, 
            Num=Num, 
            Num_devidedby_Den = Num/Den)
```

```
Data = read.table(h=T, text="
ID Type  Num  Den
A   1    2   3
A   2    5   6
B   1    1   7")

### Please let R evaluate + or / signs!
Desired_output = "
ID Type  Num  Den  Num_devidedby_Den
A   1    2   3       2/3
A   2    5   6       4/6
A   ALL  2+5 3+6     7/9
B   1    1   7       1/7
B   ALL  1   7       1/7"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in the summary by group, you need to wrap the values in `sum()` - ie, `Num = sum(Num)` then bind it back together and arrange:

```
Data %>% 
  summarise(Den=sum(Den), 
            Num=sum(Num), 
            Num_devidedby_Den = Num/Den,
            Type = "ALL",
            .by = ID) %>%
  bind_rows(Data %>% mutate(Num_devidedby_Den = Num/Den, 
                            Type = as.character(Type))) %>% 
  arrange(ID, Type)
```

Output:

```
  ID Den Num Num_devidedby_Den Type
1  A   3   2         0.6666667    1
2  A   6   5         0.8333333    2
3  A   9   7         0.7777778  ALL
4  B   7   1         0.1428571    1
5  B   7   1         0.1428571  ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- df |>
       summarise(Num_devidedby_Den = sum(Num) / sum(Den), .by = ID, Type = "ALL", Num = paste(Num, collapse = "+"), Den = paste(Den, collapse = "+"))
b <- df |> mutate(Num_devidedby_Den = Num / Den,
             across(everything(), as.character))

bind_rows(a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks, I simply used `+`  and `/` etc. in my desired_out_put to show the process. Please simply those numbers to add up or divide.